# Trying to remove all punctuation characters from a string but everything I keep getting // left in

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am trying to write a function to remove all punctuation characters from a string. I've tried several permutations on translate, replace, strip, etc. My latest attempt uses a brute force approach:

```
def clean_lower(sample):
    punct = list(string.punctuation)
    for c in punct:
        sample.replace(c, ' ')
    return sample.split()
```

That gets rid of almost all of the punctuation but I'm left with // in front of one of the words. I can't seem to find any way to remove it. I've even tried explicitly replacing it with sample.replace('//', ' ').
What do I need to do?

Comment: Please post [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @rpoleski I believe he gave us a Minimal, Reproducible Example. What is wrong in this question?

Comment: Show an input that produces wrong output. Also define what `string` is.

Comment: // is not a punctuation so are you trying to remove any symbol

Comment: Assuming that `sample` is a string, `sample.replace(c, ' ')` *does absolutely nothing* - you created a new string, but then threw it away rather than assigning it back to the variable.

Comment: I suggest taking look at [re.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split)

Answer (score 1):

using `translate` is the fastest way to remove punctuations, this will remove `//` too:

```
import string 

s = "This is! a string, with. punctuations? //"

def clean_lower(s):
    return s.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))

s = clean_lower(s)
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions

```
import re
def clean_lower(s):
    return(re.sub(r'\W','',s))
```

Above function erases any symbols except underscore

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should approach it from the perspective of what you want to keep:

For example:

```
import string

toKeep   = set(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + " ")
toRemove = set(string.printable) - toKeep
cleanUp  = str.maketrans('', '', "".join(toRemove))
```

usage:

```
s = "Hello! world of / and dice".translate(cleanUp)

# s will be 'Hello world of  and dice'
```

Answer (score 0):

as suggested by @jasonharper you need to redefine "sample" and it should work:

```
import string 

sample='// Hello?) // World!'
print(sample)

punct=list(string.punctuation)

for c in punct:
    sample=sample.replace(c,'')

print(sample.split())
```